# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getH' ...Then how to find adjoint of a matrix in my given code?

Tags: python, numpy, geth

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of rows in a matrix: "))
#key matrix for Hill Cipher
key = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
#print(key)

def key_mat(key):
    # To fill the elements in the matrix "key"
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            key[i][j] = int(input())

    #print(np.array(key))
    key = np.array(key)
    print("Key = ",key)
    return key
key_mat(n,key)

# "adjoint of a matrix" in numpy is obtained by np.matrix.getH()
#getH means get Hermitian transpose.
adj_Key = key.getH()
print(adj_Key)
```

And I got error at this line adj_Key = key.getH()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getH'

I want to find adjoint of the matrix "key", and doing so I am getting this error..How to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: That line isn't even in the code you've posted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: key_mat returns an array, but doesn''t set key in the gloabal environment.  key is still the initial list.

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a list, not a matrix. You need to convert it to a matrix before calling `getH`

```
>>> n = 5
>>> key = [[0] * n for i in range(n)]
>>> type(key)
<class 'list'>
>>> np.matrix(key).getH()
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```